# Post as frontpage - avoid duplicate content

Tags: posts, urls, slug, homepage, frontpage

On one of my WP sites I display a single post on the homepage. It's hard coded in the `index.php` like:

> If is home then show post with ID X

But now I have the post's content on the homepage but also a separate post page with the post's slug (`domain.com/post-name`).

My question: How can I eliminate the post page with the post's slug so that Wordpress throws a

> Sorry could not find anything here.

Any help or pointers into the right direction would make me really happy.

Comment: Do not publish the post.

Comment: Hey toscho thanks that's a splendid idea... but do you know any way to achieve this with the post published? I admit, I am a perfectionist :-D...

Comment: I fail to see anything "perfect" in publishing the same content twice.

Comment: Being a perfectionist in a simple world is not going to get you anywhere, it will just break your head :-). You want to reinvent the wheel because it is not 100% round, yet it cannot be rounder than it already is, and just because you cannot get it rounder, you refuse to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best way would be to redirect to the theme's 404 page in the event that the page being loaded matches the slug that you are referring to. Try this:

```
function check_undesirable_page(){
    global $post;
    if(is_page() && ($post->post_name=="YOUR-SLUG-HERE")){
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'check_undesirable_page' );
```

EDIT: Also a good idea to incorporate the `is_page()` condition (added above) to avoid undesirable consequences of the page sharing its slug with other items (in case it's a common word)

Comment: Thanks James! This is a great solution I should have come up with myself doh. :-) This problem bugged me for ages but now it works perfectly.